# How do I get the teams and the clock from this json request

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to grab the teams and the current game clock from the NFL.

I'm using this url:

http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scores/scores.json?eid=2016091500

And that returns this:

```
{
2016091500: {
  home: {
    score: {
      1: 7,
      2: 3,
      3: 14,
      4: 7,
      5: 0,
      T: 31
    },
    abbr: "BUF",
    to: 0
    },
    away: {
       score: {
         1: 6,
         2: 14,
         3: 7,
         4: 10,
         5: 0,
         T: 37
       },
       abbr: "NYJ",
       to: 2
       },
    bp: 20,
   down: 0,
   togo: 0,
   clock: "00:00",
   posteam: "BUF",
   note: null,
   redzone: false,
   stadium: "New Era Field",
   media: {
     radio: {
      home: null,
      away: null
     },
     tv: "CBS",
     sat: null,
     sathd: null
     },
     yl: "",
     qtr: "Final"
},
...
}
```

The 2016091500 is the game ID and it's unique.

Thanks

Comment: Please add your expected result

Comment: Plenty of solutions exist, I selected [one that matches your example quite closely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110988/deserializing-json-with-numbers-as-keys). If you don't agree, read [ask] and share your research. Search for "C# deserialize JSON with numeric keys" or something like that.