# class name is number json serializing in c# issue

Tags: c#, json

{
  "ChapelID": 5,
  "Name": "the-gazebo",
  "Date": "2017-08-01T00:00:00",
  "LastUpdated": "2017-06-21T14:21:33.2027903-07:00",
  "Days": {
    "30": {
      "IsAvailable": true,
      "IsWeekend": false,
      "Slots": {
        "1504108800": {
          "IsAvailable": true,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504110600": {
          "IsAvailable": true,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504112400": {
          "IsAvailable": true,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504114200": {
          "IsAvailable": true,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504116000": {
          "IsAvailable": true,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504117800": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504119600": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504121400": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504123200": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504125000": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504126800": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504128600": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504130400": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504132200": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504134000": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504135800": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504137600": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504139400": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504141200": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504143000": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504144800": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504146600": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504148400": {
          "IsAvailable": true,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504150200": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504152000": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504153800": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504155600": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        }
      }
    },
    "31": {
      "IsAvailable": true,
      "IsWeekend": false,
      "Slots": {
        "1504195200": {
          "IsAvailable": true,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504197000": {
          "IsAvailable": true,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504198800": {
          "IsAvailable": true,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504200600": {
          "IsAvailable": true,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504202400": {
          "IsAvailable": true,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504204200": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504206000": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504207800": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504209600": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504211400": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504213200": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504215000": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504216800": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504218600": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504220400": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504222200": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504224000": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504225800": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504227600": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504229400": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504231200": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504233000": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504234800": {
          "IsAvailable": true,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504236600": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504238400": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504240200": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1504242000": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        }
      }
    },
    "01": {
      "IsAvailable": true,
      "IsWeekend": false,
      "Slots": {
        "1501603200": {
          "IsAvailable": true,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501605000": {
          "IsAvailable": true,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501606800": {
          "IsAvailable": true,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501608600": {
          "IsAvailable": true,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501610400": {
          "IsAvailable": true,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501612200": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501614000": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501615800": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501617600": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501619400": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501621200": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501623000": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501624800": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501626600": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501628400": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501630200": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501632000": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501633800": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501635600": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501637400": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501639200": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501641000": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501642800": {
          "IsAvailable": true,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501644600": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501646400": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501648200": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501650000": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        }
      }
    },
    "03": {
      "IsAvailable": true,
      "IsWeekend": false,
      "Slots": {
        "1501776000": {
          "IsAvailable": true,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501777800": {
          "IsAvailable": true,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501779600": {
          "IsAvailable": true,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501781400": {
          "IsAvailable": true,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501783200": {
          "IsAvailable": true,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501785000": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501786800": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501788600": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501790400": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501792200": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501794000": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501795800": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501797600": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501799400": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501801200": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501803000": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501804800": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501806600": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501808400": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501810200": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501812000": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501813800": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501815600": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501817400": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501819200": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501821000": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        },
        "1501822800": {
          "IsAvailable": false,
          "Fee": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

```
//some what works
public class Days
{
    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
    public bool IsWeekend { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string, string>> Slots {get;set;}
}
public class CalendarDataJson
{
    public int ChapelID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,Days> Days { get; set; }
}
```

unable to serialize this json in c# any help is appreciated this is because the class name is giving issue as it can'nt be a number

Comment: Looks like they (`Days` and `Slots`)should be `Dictionary<string, SomeType>` ...

Comment: maybe this will work for you [Deserializing JSON with numbers as keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110988/deserializing-json-with-numbers-as-keys)

Comment: not able to serialize the slots part of it however hard i try

Comment: public class Days
    {
        public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
        public bool IsWeekend { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>> Slots {get;set;}
    }
    
    public class CalendarDataJson
    {
        public int ChapelID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string LastUpdated { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string,Days> Days { get; set; }
    }

Comment: thanks kogoia,marc gravell

Comment: Please [edit] your question to a) include the code that you put in your comment, and to trim down your JSON to the minimum necessary to show your error, and then [format that JSON as code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: the comment itself solved my problem thanks to kogoia,marc gravell should i put the solution along with question ?

Comment: i am not being allowed to post answer down below so added it in comment

Comment: issue is not fully solved