# json mapping issue c#

Tags: c#, .net, json

unable to create a class to deserailize this json c# cause the number is causing issue while mapping any help is appreciated 
inception of creating class itself is the problem

```
{//this is the class name
"1504076400": {
    "VenueKey": "the-gazebo",
    "IsShortBook": false,
    "IsSaturday": false,
    "Slots": [{
            "TS": 1504098000,
            "String": "08-30-2017 6:00 AM",
            "IsAvailable": false
        },
        {
            "TS": 1504099800,
            "String": "08-30-2017 6:30 AM",
            "IsAvailable": false
        }
    ]
},//these numbers are causing problem
"1504162800": {
    "VenueKey": "the-gazebo",
    "IsShortBook": false,
    "IsSaturday": false,
    "Slots": [{
            "TS": 1504184400,
            "String": "08-31-2017 6:00 AM",
            "IsAvailable": false
        },
        {
            "TS": 1504186200,
            "String": "08-31-2017 6:30 AM",
            "IsAvailable": false
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: c# does not allow a numerical class name

Comment: These are obviously the same type of object, but the "class name" is different for each one... you can override a class name, but according to your theory, you have not one class represented here, but an infinite number.  Can you try maybe deserializing to a Dictionary<int, MyVenueClass>?  The number looks more like a key than a class name.  In any event, this doesn't look like well-formed JSON - if you don't have any control over the sending code, you may want to reach out to the sender to see what their intention is...

Comment: tried its not working

Comment: you must deserialize to a Dictionary<string,MyVenueClass> - The JSON property name is always a string and serializers will only map it to a string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing JSON with numbers as keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110988/deserializing-json-with-numbers-as-keys)

Comment: @ElementalPete What makes you feel this does not look like well formed JSON? According to http://json.org (the official JSON documentation) it is valid (to me). Please point out where it does violate the rules.

Comment: @SirRufo - According to Google's naming guidelines, property names should be meaningful names with defined semantics, and the first character must be a letter, an underscore, or a dollar sign.  The purpose of that is to avoid violating language conventions like this does.  .Net is not some "edge case" - it's a pretty popular language and should be supported by well-constructed json.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see problems neither deserialization nor json. Model classe can look like:

```
class Venue
{
    public string VenueKey { get; set; }

    public bool IsShortBook { get; set; }

    public bool IsSaturday { get; set; }

    public Slot[] Slots { get; set; }
}

class Slot
{
    public string TS { get; set; }

    public string @String { get; set; }

    public bool ISAvailable { get; set; }
}
```

And desirialization works fine:
`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Venue>>(json);`

Comment: {"Error converting value \"the-gazebo\" to type 'TimeSlotChapelProblem.Venue'. Path '1504076400.VenueKey', line 3, position 29."}

Comment: Are you sure? I've checked with JSON.Net version 10 and version 6. All works fine. What exactly do you do? [working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eFX7aX)

Comment: yes sure this is just sample json that i posted actual one is very long