# Problem: display JSON data but some of the parent data is integer

Tags: c#, json

```
{
    "recsonpage": "1",
    "recsindb": "1",
    "1": {
        "orders.orderid": "84344969",
        "entity.customerid": "19421067",
        "entity.entityid": "84344969",
        "orders.autorenew": "false",
        "orders.endtime": "1572414460",
        "orders.resellerlock": "false",
        "orders.timestamp": "2018-10-30 05:47:41.791511+00",
        "orders.customerlock": "true",
        "entity.entitytypeid": "87",
        "entity.currentstatus": "Active",
        "entitytype.entitytypekey": "dotco",
        "orders.transferlock": "true",
        "orders.creationtime": "1540878460",
        "orders.privacyprotection": "false",
        "entitytype.entitytypename": ".CO Domain Name",
        "orders.creationdt": "1540878459",
        "entity.description": "testlbapi.co"
    },
   "2": {
       "orders.orderid": "84421837",
       "entity.customerid": "19442287",
       "entity.entityid": "84421837",
       "orders.autorenew": "true",
       "orders.endtime": "1573084799",
       "orders.resellerlock": "false",
       "orders.timestamp": "2018-11-06 17:06:25.269568+00",
       "orders.customerlock": "false",
       "entity.entitytypeid": "450",
       "entity.currentstatus": "Active",
       "entitytype.entitytypekey": "dotspace",
       "orders.transferlock": "false",
       "orders.creationtime": "1541523983",
       "orders.privacyprotection": "false",
       "entitytype.entitytypename": ".SPACE Domain Names",
       "orders.creationdt": "1541435012",
       "entity.description": "thairaksaa.space"
   },
  "3": {
       "orders.orderid": "84421838",
       "entity.customerid": "19442287",
       "entity.entityid": "84421838",
       "orders.autorenew": "true",
       "orders.endtime": "1604682389",
       "orders.resellerlock": "false",
       "orders.timestamp": "2018-11-06 17:06:30.199466+00",
       "orders.customerlock": "true",
       "entity.entitytypeid": "3",
       "entity.currentstatus": "Active",
       "entitytype.entitytypekey": "domcno",
       "orders.transferlock": "true",
       "orders.creationtime": "1541523989",
       "orders.privacyprotection": "false",
       "entitytype.entitytypename": ".COM Domain Name",
       "orders.creationdt": "1541435014",
       "entity.description": "thairaksaa.com"
  }
}
```

I need to get the child data of "1" parent data. I was trying to deserialize this json data but I'm having a problem because the parent data is a number.

UPDATE: How will I get the parent data integer if they are 2 or more? because, on my API, the json data has different number of records depends on customer's order list.

Comment: Do you have C# classes for this? Can you show them? What library are you using for serialization? JSON.NET?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing JSON with numbers as keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110988/deserializing-json-with-numbers-as-keys)

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here (see [ask]). Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: Hi John, below is the library   

var MyDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDetail>(json);
public class MyDetail
            {
                public string recsonpage
                {get;set;}

                public string recsindb
                {get;set;}
            }

Comment: Hi krishna, I will check on that . thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to serializat.

If the key contains a special word you can try to use [JsonProperty](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm) to mark binding key from your `JSON`.

```
public partial class JsonModel
{
    [JsonProperty("1")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> obj1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("recsonpage")]
    public string Recsonpage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("recsindb")]
    public string Recsindb { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use like

```
var MyDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModel>(json);
```

**Note**

There are two way can create model easily.

- You can use Web Essentials in Visual Studio, use Edit > Paste special > paste JSON as a class, you can easier to know the relation between Json and model.
- If you can't use Web Essentials you can instead of use https://app.quicktype.io/?l=csharp online JSON to Model class.

You can try to use those models to carry your JSON Format.

Comment: Hi D-shih, this is the output after I tried your suggestion

recsonpage: 1
recsindb: 1
1: System.Collections.Generic.Dircyionary'2[System.String,System.String]

Comment: @IrisLorrenHequibal It work good in c# online https://dotnetfiddle.net/gBTlmd

Comment: Hi @d-shih oh I see. Yes it's working now on my end. Thank you so much!

Comment: @IrisLorrenHequibal No problem glad to help you can mark this answer if that help you :)

Comment: last question D-shih, since that json does have 1 data, what if it has 2 or more? because my API has more than 1 record depends on the customer's domain list. the one I provided is from a customer that has 1 data.

Comment: Could you edit your question and post your `JSON` data?

Comment: sure d-shih I will edit my question and post the new one

Comment: I d-shih I posted my updated question and json data. thank you

Comment: Could you moddify your `JSON` format like https://app.quicktype.io?share=CpJf5RTsX32zU4kd1dIA

Comment: @IrisLorrenHequibal Becasue there too many object in your `JSON` they should be in an array.

Comment: I see. I got it. I will try that array. thank you!